# C++ operator overloading for equality

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm very new to C++ and trying to get up this simple example working, but for some reason I get unexpected results.

#### Code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node{
    string data;
    node *next;
    node *prev;

    node() {}

    bool operator==(const node &rhs) const {
        return data == rhs.data;
    }
};

int main(){
    bool loop=true;
    node* one = new node();
    one->data = "oddly specific";

    node* two = new node();
    two->data = "Something else";

    node* three = new node();
    three->data = "oddly specific";

    if (one == two)
        cout << "one == two";
    else
        cout << "one != two";
    if (one == three)
        cout << "one == three";
    else
        cout << "one != three";

    cout << endl;

    if(one->data == two->data)
        cout << "one == two";
    else
        cout << "one != two";
    if(one->data == three->data)
        cout << "one == three";
    else
        cout << "one != three";
}
```

I'm trying to create custom operator for ==

```
bool operator==(const node &rhs) const { return data == rhs.data; }
```

The second line prints what I expected to happen, it looks like the operator overloaded function is simply not run?

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question, along with actual and expected output.

Comment: `one` and `two` are pointers, not `nodes`.

Comment: I included ideone link in the main post. It prints 
one != twoone != three
When I want it to print
one != twoone == three

Which is what happens when you compare the "data" field directly

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using pointers and `new` in your code? It just gives you something else to get wrong when you're trying to understand simple concepts like operator overloading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to dereference the node structure, instead of comparing pointers:

```
if (*one == *two) {}
```

But as others pointed out, you should consider not using pointers, so just do:

```
node one;
node two;
....
if (one == two) {}
```

Comment: Same problem as this code: `int *j = new int; int *k = new int; *j = 0; *k = 0; if (j == k) ...` They won't be equivalent because they point to different things.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `one == three` you are actually comparing pointers rather than the objects themselves. Try: `*one == *three`.